# Mean-Variance optimization with no short selling

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, mean-variance, markowitz

I am wondering how I can find the vector of Lagrange multipliers $\mu$ for the non-negativity constraint of the following problem:

$$ L(w,\lambda, \mu) = w^{T}\Sigma w - \lambda(w -1) + \mu w $$

So far what I cam up with is, that $\mu$ can be isolated with first order condition $ \frac{\partial L }{\partial w} $:

$$ \Sigma w - \lambda = - \mu $$
$$ \mu = \lambda - \Sigma w $$

Is there a way I can find a explicit solution for $ \mu $?

I have no background in finance nor optimization, every suggestion or comment is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is $\mu$ the expected returns vector of the assets? Why do you want to solve this when it's just a given input to the model. you should be interested in $w$ (or $\lambda$) only

Comment: $\mu$ is the Lagrange multiplier of the positivity constraint (i.e. w > 0)

Answer (score 4):

You can use Lagrangian only with equal type constaints. There are inqualities in your problem, namely $w \ge 0$ and $w \le 1$. Hence Lagrange method cannot be employed here.

According to tags you added to the question, you are solving Markowitz optimization problem. One of its formulation (maximizing profit and minimizing risk at the same time) is

$$
f = \mu ^T w - \lambda w^T\Sigma w \rightarrow \text{MAX},
$$

subjected to $0 \le  w \le 1$ and $\sum w_i =1$. Vector $\mu$ contains expected returns of assets in portfolio, $\Sigma$ is covariance matrix of returns and parameter $\lambda$ is used for setting averse to risk. Higher $\lambda$ means higher risk averse.

This task can be solved by so-called [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming).

However, in practice you can employ MS Excel solver. As a solving method, please select *GRG Non-linear*. This is so-called gradient method and it can cope with quadratic problem task succesfully (this can be even proven mathematically).

Comment: is there another method that can yield an explicit solution?

Comment: @secretsanta: I expanded the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I know I can get the dual variables from such a solver I just wanted to see if there is another way

Comment: are you calling $r$ what he is calling $\mu$?

Comment: @develarist: You are right, corrected.

Comment: @develarist: But on the other hand, it seems that mu was used as Lagrange multiplier for non negative weight which Is wrong as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: It is not clear to me why it is wrong. I just read about the KKT conditions that deal with such a Lagrangian and how it surmounts to solving the KKT system. I guess what I was wondering is if there is an analytic solution to the get the Lagrange multipliers of the positivity constraint

Comment: @secretsanta: As I mentioned in my answer, Lagrangian method can be used only for optimization with constraints in form of equalities. In your cae $\mu w$ means condition $w=0$ which does not make sense.